# Daisy chained network with shared internet

Tags: networking, router, switch

The network i'm working on is a group of separate business in a small business park that all share an internet connection. This is someone elses solution that I have to replace. no notes, no passwords to any of the gear already here.

There is a single point where the internet comes in, goes to a switch that then daisy chains to another switch then that to another switch and then that to another etc, around the business park. Each of the ports in each of the switches plugs into a different tenants router WAN port and that router then does the DHCP for each tenants network (via LAN port to tenants own switch)

As a solution I have to replace like with like -if I setup each of the tenant routers with 192.168.0.1 on the LAN side and 10.10.10.x on the WAN side, am i right in thinking that because the WAN port is connected to the shared switch the individual tenants networks wont interact with each other?

thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chaining the switches isn't good network design. If one switch in the chain fails, the rest is offline.

Apparently, NAT is used on each tennant's router. Unless there's port forwarding configured on the routers, the tennants will not be able to connect into each other's LANs. That however is up to the tennants and their router/firewall configuration. Technically, this network design does nothing to stop them from communicating if they want.

If you need to really isolate the tennants you need to put each port in a separate VLAN. On the main router, you then connect to each VLAN with a logical interface. On alternative way would be to set up "private VLAN" or "port isolation" (depending on the switch vendor).

Comment: I know chained is crappy but they won’t re-wire the park. Thanks for your message - the tenants router is provided and controlled by the park not the tenant, they only have their own switches...

Comment: Apparently the tennants have no serious requirements for security... (Unless there's some decent SLA.) Depending on the cabling that's actually present you might be able to rewire to multiple, shorter chains or close the chain to a full loop (along with spanning tree, of course).